# AWS APi Gateway getting response message as ": "Endpoint request timed out" 504 from AWS Service

Tags: server-sent-events

I have deployed Spring boot Java server sent event application in AWS Service.
My Html eventsource index.html trying to access using AWS API gateway end point url(where I configured Java server sent event application rest api url).

The Following things are observed ans wroking:
1. I able to connect to Back End AWS server.
2. Event source URL register its request in Java Serve sent event application
3. But response is not getting from AWS serve to APi GAteway.getting timeout
error after 30 seconds.
Kindly Help me on to fix this issue